# how we can a part of text in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

consider the following column in my data set.

```
Norm
marketer
summer
vip 
teacher
vip
manager at hotel
```

I want if I have `manager at hotel` come after `vip` change `vip` to `vip of manager` how I can do that?

output

```
Norm
marketer
summer
vip
teacher
vip of manager
manager at hotel
```

Comment: `df.Norm = df.Norm.replace('manager at hotel,vip', 'manager at hotel,vip of manager')`

Comment: Do you want something to do it dynamically, or manually? If you do want dynamically for each row, then the solution that @Mayank Porwal proposed, is not what you want.

Comment: @LoukasPap I edited the question it was not something that I wanted

Comment: @elham Reopened your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `df`:

```
In [1190]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Norm': ['marketer', 'summer', 'vip', 'teacher', 'vip', 'manager at hotel']})

In [1191]: df
Out[1191]: 
               Norm
0          marketer
1            summer
2               vip
3           teacher
4               vip
5  manager at hotel
```

Use:

```
In [1175]: df['new'] = df.Norm.shift(-1)

In [1194]: ix = df[df.Norm.eq('vip') & df.new.eq('manager at hotel')].index

In [1197]: df.loc[ix, 'Norm'] = df.loc[ix, 'Norm'] + '  of manager'

In [1199]: df.drop('new', 1, inplace=True)

In [1200]: df
Out[1200]: 
               Norm
0          marketer
1            summer
2               vip
3           teacher
4   vip  of manager
5  manager at hotel
```